# Upgraded to React Native 0.62.0 Getting Warning Sign - "Calling `getNode()` on the ref of Animated component is no longer necessary

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I just upgrade my react native app to 0.62.0, and now my app keeps getting this warning sign

```
ReactNativeFiberHostComponent: Calling `getNode()` on the ref of an Animated component 
is no longer necessary. You can now directly use the ref instead. 
This method will be removed in a future release.
```

I'm not sure why this issue is showing up? Can someone please explain?

I also see Stack

```
ref.getNode |
createAnimatedComponent.js:129:20

SafeView#_updateMeasurements | index.js:192:14

SafeView#componentDidUpdate | index.js:154:9
```

**Update**

I believe this might be coming from SafeAreaView from react-navigation

Answer (score 6):

I also came to this warning after upgraded ro RN 0.62.1, and I didn't use `getNode()` at all, turns out it came from a depedencies that I use, called `react-native-snap-carousel` because they build it with FlatList and possibly using the `getNode()` as well.

And now there's an open issue about this in their GitHub repo that we can follow, here's the link to [the issue](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/issues/672)

### Update

this also came from package `react-native-safe-area-view`, possibly your app is using this package and now they have released new version to fix `getNode()` deprecation, [see this PR](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-safe-area-view/pull/110)

so instead of fixing the file directly yourself, you just need to update the package, simply run: `npm i react-native-safe-area-view`

Hope that's help :)

Answer (score 5):

## To quick fix this go to node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view => index.js

at line 192 change

this.view.getNode().measureInWindow((winX, winY, winWidth, winHeight)

to

this.view.measureInWindow((winX, winY, winWidth, winHeight)

Comment: İnstead of this you can now just update your node modules `npm i react-native-safe-area-view`

Comment: You can apply those changes mentioned in answer and create a patch for it in your project https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package `npx patch-package react-native-safe-area-view` which will get saved to a patches folder

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `react-native-snap-carousel` you can fix it by modifying your node module locally.

first go to

```
 ./node_modules/react-native-snap-carousel/src/Carousel.js
```

change

```
const AnimatedFlatList = FlatList ? Animated.createAnimatedComponent(FlatList) : null;
const AnimatedScrollView = Animated.Animated.createAnimatedComponent(ScrollView);
```

into

```
const AnimatedFlatList = FlatList ? Animated.FlatList : null;
const AnimatedScrollView = Animated.ScrollView;
```

and finally, change your `_getWrappedRef` function to

```
_getWrappedRef () {
 return this._carouselRef
}
```

This will stop the warning until we have an update on that package.

Comment: I am just updated `react-native-snap-carousel` to latest version and warning was gone.

Comment: I updated react-native-snap-carousel ( "^3.9.1") as described above but I still have a warning. Maybe the message comes from a different library, how to check it? The warning begins like this: Calling getNode() on the ref of an Animated component is no longer necessary. You can now directly use the ref instead. This method will be removed in a future release.', 'ReactNativeFiberHostComponent', '\n SafeView.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the [blog post](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2020/03/26/version-0.62) announcing the release of RN62, `getNode()` is now deprecated. You can just use `ref` without calling `getNode()`. See this [commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/66e72bb4e00aafbcb9f450ed5db261d98f99f82a).

Comment: The thing is, I'm not using anything with getNode, is it possible that a package that I'm bringing in is using it? I'm not sure how I can see which package uses it? Is there an easy way to find out?

Comment: Update - i think it might be coming from SafeAreaView from react-navigation

Comment: yeah, the warning can come from some of your dependencies, like you mention

Answer (score 0):

the issue will happen when you use createAnimatedComponent for components while its already exist in animated library for example if we use it to FlatList this warning will be showing
for fix it just call componenty directly

for more detail [enter link description here](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/issues/672#issuecomment-611512460)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
return this._carouselRef && this._carouselRef.getNode && this._carouselRef.getNode();
```

to

```
return this._carouselRef;
```

*Removing getNode() will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

i find that error in my project.
Fix: copy "getNode()" and find all in your project, delete it.
[Delete warning getNode()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yoB3.png)