# React Native showing warning "Calling `getNode()` on the ref of an Animated component is no longer necessary. "

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

The full warning is " Calling `getNode()` on the ref of an Animated component is no longer necessary. You can now directly use the ref instead. This method will be removed in a future release. ReactNativeFiberHostComponent"

It shows the error even though i am not using getNode on my code,from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60910385/upgraded-to-react-native-0-62-0-getting-warning-sign-calling-getnode-on-t) i found out that it is coming from SafeAreaview in react-navigation.Any ways to fix this?

Comment: I have already made a PR here. https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-safe-area-view/pull/110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade [react-native-safe-area-view](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-safe-area-view) library to >='1.1.0'